# Does Lumia 1020 support USB OTG in either WP8.1 or W10M?

Tags: nokia-lumia-1020, usb

1020 was once a flagship model. Will it support USB OTG?

Answer (score 2):

The Lumia 1020 was released with Windows Phone 8.0, which did not support USB OTG. Additionally, there is no supported build of Windows 10 Mobile for the Lumia 1020.

Windows 10 Mobile was the first version to apparently support USB OTG, although it is [currently difficult to determine which devices support it](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/13963/106).